# How to detect a name from an .mp3 file with Python 3

Tags: python, audio, metadata

I'm new to Stackoverflow. I just want to detect a name in an .mp3 file that already exists and when it recognises it, I want the program to beep, or to produce a sound. I already know .mp3 metadata, but it doesn't work how I want to. Please help me! :)

Comment: Do you want to detect a name in the audio content of the file or in the file name? Can you add a snippet of code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to detect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import winsound
import os

frequency = 2500  
duration = 1000  

keyword = 'file'
for fname in os.listdir('directory/with/files'):
    if keyword in fname:
        print(fname, "has the keyword")
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only have a problem, I use MacOs. This only works with Windows.

Comment: use pygame library to make sound